# Laptop issue (wifi and mouse)

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, mouse, wireless-mouse

I have Dell Inspiron 14z laptop.

If I put wireless mouse receiver to USB port, it works after a few minutes. (It worked right away before, but now it has some delay)

Wi-fi connection is not very clear. For the same wifi network, my cell phone connects very well, but my laptop has some problem.

Might it be my laptop problem? It may be the mouse or wifi network that has problem. How can I check if my laptop has problem?

Comment: Doe the wireless mouse and Wi-Fi both operate using 2.4 GHz? You could try changing the Wi-Fi channel. Use channel 1, 6, or 11.

Comment: My question would be does the WiFi work well when the mouse receiver is not connected? Wifi channel is infrastructure based, not device based, the OP may not have any control over the WiFi channel. Try moving the wireless receiver to a different usb port, on the other side of the laptop if possible, or get a Bluetooth mouse and receiver.